# Is there a specific name for the highest energy state in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, quantum-states

In quantum mechanics, the **lowest** energy state is called the **ground state**. I am wondering if there is a name for the **highest** energy state? Should I call it the top state, or the ceiling state, or the highest state, or ... ?

I am asking this because the highest energy state of a bounded many-body local Hamiltonian[1] shares many similar properties as the ground state, such as zero temperature[2] and the area-law entanglement entropy, and can exhibit phenomena such as spontaneous symmetry broken or topological order, which are different from the finite energy density excited states in the bulk of the energy spectrum. So I am asking if people has given the highest energy state any specific name.

[1] For an example, consider the Heisenberg model of spins in 3D

$$H=\sum_{\langle i j\rangle}S_i\cdot S_j.$$

The ground state is an antiferomagnetic state, and the highest energy state is a ferromagnetic state (as the ground state of $-H$). Both states break the symmetry spontaneously.

[2] For zero and negative temperature, please check  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_state

Comment: Why would you give a name to something that doesn't exist? I have no idea why you think that anything can have "zero temperature". That is clearly forbidden by the third law of thermodynamics and quantum mechanics doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: What about ceiling state?

Comment: @CuriousOne When people talked about zero temperature quantum phase transitions, do you think they do not understand the 3rd law of thermodynamics? Even if you are not comfortable with zero temperature, the highest energy state itself is something that **exist** for any bounded Hamiltonian.

Comment: How about you call it the "highest energy state".

Comment: The "heaven state"? Oh, gag me with a spoon. Barf. Barf-a-rama.

Comment: @EverettYou Could you give an example of a Hamiltonian with a highest energy state? It seems like quite an odd idea: realistically you could always excite the system to higher energy, although this might be a somewhat destructive process. I don't really understand the discussion and objections about zero temperature, obviously all pure quantum states are at "zero temperature".

Comment: @MarkMitchison I have edited the post by providing an example.

Comment: EverettYou: I'd suggest calling such a state the "roof state" of the system (while "ceiling" seems a better match for "floor"). But since there's no established (short) name yet at all, you should generally add the description "the highest energy state" at least in parentheses. Btw., a related, already established notion is that of the/an "asymptotically free state" of a suitable system (i.e. having the least energy as to not being "bound" anymore; if it exists). However, there isn't necessarily some "state with the highest energy still less than that of an asymptotically free state".

Comment: "$T = -\varepsilon$" or "infinitesimal negative temperature" state?  I think I once heard Sid Paramesawan use a name for this state, but I forget what he said.

Comment: (That's an "epsilon," but it's hard to read with the small font for comments)

Comment: Top state is not fancy, but has no ambiguity...

Answer (score 1):

For the simple [hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c4) there exists a ground state, then there are energy levels where an excited electron can reside, and then there is the zero energy level, so yes, there is a name in this case. From the zero energy  level  the maximum energy is given up, when the electron falls to the ground state, so it is the highest potential energy state.

[image: hydrogen]